# How do I download a file on click in reactjs from download Url firebase storage?

Tags: reactjs

This is what I implemented:

```
downloadFile=(file)=>{
        var element=document.createElement('a');
        element.style.display= "none";
        element.setAttribute('href', file.fileUrl)
        element.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        document.body.appendChild(element)
        element.click()
        document.body.removeChild(element) 
    }
```

This is working fine for .ai files but not for .pdf or .jpeg. Instead of downloading the file, the browser opens it in a separate window. I want to enable download file feature and not open file. How do I fix this issue? Is there an alternative way to download the file from url from browser?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `download` attribute instead of `href`.
See [element a DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).